# Can I charge the battery with just a USB cable?

Tags: hardware, psp

While perusing a local second-hand charity shop, I stumbled upon a PSP for a steal!  However, the one "problem" mentioned by the clerk was that it was without a power supply.  After handling the device, I also noticed the battery had started to bulge.

I'm shopping around for an OEM battery at a reasonable price but while I wait I wanted to ask, can I charge the battery via the USB with just the USB cable?  Also, does it matter if the battery is completely dead?  I think I read somewhere that charging via USB is possible, however, you first have to cut on a couple settings from within a config menu.  If true, that seems unfortunate.

Anyway, I'd like to know the truth, for sure before buying a power adapter.  If getting one is inevitable, I may as well just order it with the battery.  Also, this is a PSP-3001 model, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, although extremely slowly, just imagine it as the same thing as your phone.

Go to settings>system setting>USB charging-turn it on.

However, keep in mind there is a certain model that does not has that function:

> PSP 1001 phat

The others, like yours, should.

Comment: Because the video may end up being taken down at some point, it is important to include the main points of the video in your answer. If you wouldn't mind editing that in, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Sure, my bad :)

Comment: For future reference, it's okay to have videos in your answer. It's just important to write down the information in the video in case it is unavailable one day.

Comment: Ok, curious, even if the charging setting isn't on, do you know if you can still cut on the device, with it plugged into the USB, if the battery is dead AND this setting hasn't been turned on yet?  Otherwise, I'll need to find a power adapter just so I can cut on the device to turn on these settings.

Comment: Unfortunatly no but using a leased adapder seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

PSP use lithium ion batteries. If it starts to bulge *DO NOT RECHARGE IT*. Bring it to a proper disposal place for such batteries.

Remember all the exploding laptops, phones and balancing-boards-that-some-people-think-hover? Yeah, lithium ion battery fire. You don't want that.

If there's a noticeable bulge don't use it, store it carefully and bring it to a proper disposal place (it's safe to handle as long as you don't do dumb things like heat or puncture it).